# On the nested square roots $\sqrt{1^2+\sqrt{2^2+\sqrt{3^2 ...+\sqrt{(n-1)^2+\sqrt{n^2}}}}}$

Tags: radicals, nested-radicals

I saw this on quora:

Use induction to show that
$\sqrt{1^2+\sqrt{2^2+\sqrt{3^2
...+\sqrt{(n-1)^2+\sqrt{n^2}}}}}
\le 2
$.

My question is simpler.

If
$x_n
=\sqrt{1^2+\sqrt{2^2+\sqrt{3^2
...+\sqrt{(n-1)^2+\sqrt{n^2}}}}}
$,
how can $x_{n+1}$
be expressed in terms of
$x_n$?

No ellipsis
("...")
or iterations
are allowed.

This is all I've come up with, 
but it doesn't seem to be
of much use.

Let

$\begin{array}\\
f_{n}(x)
&=\sqrt{1^2+\sqrt{2^2+\sqrt{3^2
...+\sqrt{n^2+x}}}}\\
f_{n+1}(x)
&=\sqrt{1^2+\sqrt{2^2+\sqrt{3^2
...+\sqrt{n^2+\sqrt{(n+1)^2+x}}}}}\\
&=f_n(\sqrt{(n+1)^2+x})\\
\end{array}
$

so if
$y
=\sqrt{(n+1)^2+x}
$,
$f_n(y)
=f_{n+1}(x)
$.
$y^2
=(n+1)^2+x
$,
so
$x
=y^2-(n+1)^2
$
or
$f_{n+1}(y^2-(n+1)^2)
=f_n(y)
$.

Comment: Your question isn't necessarily "simpler", or more tractable, than the one you saw on quora. If anything, it may be harder.

Comment: The trick of this problem is in the wording "use induction". This does not mean that the inequality is proved by using induction on $n$, but rather by proving a generalized statement, namely $\sqrt{k^2 + \sqrt{(k + 1)^2 + \sqrt{\cdots + \sqrt{n^2}}}} \leq k + 1$ by using induction on $k$ (or in fact on $n - k$). There is not so much connection between $x_n$ and $x_{n + 1}$.

Answer (score 4):

[Not intended as a complete answer. It doesn't relate $x_n$ and $x_{n+1}$ as requested by OP, in part because that's not the "right" thing to look at.]

It is often harder to deal with inserting the variable just at the very extreme end of the nested roots. This makes intuitive sense in part because the function is so un-sensitive to changing just that value. E.g. I expect that $f_n (2^{2^n}) - f_n (0) < 1 $ (but am not fully certain).

It is generally more useful to define the recursive nature by "shifting" the terms, which can be done in the following way:

Let $g_n(x) = \sqrt{ (x+1)^2 + \sqrt{ (x+2)^2  + \sqrt{ \ldots + \sqrt{ (x+n)^2 }}}}$

Then, $ g_{n} (x) = \sqrt{ (x+1)^2 + g_{n-1}(x+1)}$.

We are asked to show that $g_n(0) \leq 2$.

---

Why is this possibly the "right" thing to look at?

One naive/obvious/intuitive/brute-force approach is to "square both sides, subtract terms, and repeat till we get everything".  In the language of this notation, we can write it as:

WTS $g_n(0) \leq 2 $
$\Leftarrow g_{n-1} (1) \leq 2^2 - 1^2 = 3 $
$\Leftarrow g_{n-2} (2) \leq 3^2 - 2^2 = 5 $
$\Leftarrow g_{n-3} (3) \leq 5^2 - 3^2 = 16 $
$\Leftarrow g_{n-4} (4) \leq 16^2 - 4^2 = 240 $
$\Leftarrow \vdots $
$ \Leftarrow g_1 (n-1) \leq $ ??

Now, $g_1 (n-1) = n$, and it is clear that the RHS is huge (almost squaring each time), so the last inequality should almost always be true, especially in a hand-waving context.

Rigorizing this simply requires finding a good bound on the RHS. By staring and conjecturing really hard, one might come up with:
$g_1 (n-1) < n+1 $
$\Rightarrow g_2 (n-2) < \sqrt{ (n-1)^2 + n+1} < n$ for $n-2 \geq 0$
$\Rightarrow g_3 (n-3) < \sqrt{ (n-2)^2 + n} < n-1$ for $n-3 \geq 0$
$\Rightarrow \vdots $
$\Rightarrow g_{n-1} (1) < \sqrt{ 2^2 + 4} < 3$
$\Rightarrow g_n(0) < \sqrt{1^2 + 3 } = 2 $.

Note: It's somewhat surprising that we have a linear bound (though that makes the math nice). There are other possibilities that make use of the exponential growth.

---

To proceed by induction, one would have to guess that the strengthened hypothesis is

> $g_n(m) < m+2$ for $ m \geq 0$.

This can be easily proven by inducting on $n$, and is essentially that reversed chain
The base case is $ g_1 (m) = m+1 < m+2 $.
The induction step is $ g_{n+1} (m) = \sqrt{ (m+1)^2 + g_n(m+1) } < \sqrt{(m+1)^2 + m+3 } < m+2. $
Hence $g_n(0) < 2 $.

---

There could be other ways to prove the problem by induction. For example, another strengthened induction approach would be to show that $ x_n < 2 - h(n)$, in which case we want to show that $x_{n+1} - x_n < h(n) - h(n+1) $.

This might be why studying how $x_{n+1}$ is related to $x_n$ could be helpful. However, as explained earlier, it's very hard to get a handle on this difference, because of how nested everything is.

Comment: I upvoted because it answered the original question, but did not accept because it did not answer mine. Quite nice, though.

Comment: @martycohen My point is that your $x_n$ isn't the "right" thing to look at. My definition of $g_n(x) $ gets at the "meta" of your question, which offers a different interpretation of what $x_n$ should be. I've added more explanations.